# Excel get value between 2 dates

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, array, lookup

I'm attempting to retrieve a value from a table with set dates

For example, given the table below, if a user entered the date 01/07/2019 it would retrieve D or 4. If a user entered 01/07/2017then it would retrieve B or 2.

```
    A           B           C   D   E
1   1/01/2016   31/12/2016      A   1
2   1/01/2017   31/12/2017      B   2
3   1/01/2018   31/12/2018      C   3
4   1/01/2019   31/12/2019      D   4
5   1/01/2020   31/12/2020      E   5
6   1/01/2021   31/12/2021      F   6
7   1/01/2022   31/12/2022      G   7
```

*Note: Dates will never overlap.*

I've seen examples of retrieving numbers using the `INDEX` function however i cannot get it to work with dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your data is sorted you can use `VLOOKUP`:
`=VLOOKUP(F1,$A$1:$D$7,3,TRUE)`
[image]

Comment: Huh, I never even thought about using a Vlookup. For some reason I thought it matched on exact values only. Thanks!